# How to combine the getRange() function with a forLoop when trying to piece together your data in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**EDIT:**
Since my problem is rather difficult to describe I added an example of my data which hopefully shows what I'd like to achieve:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wa_z2e2br53usul3uMy8nczXushvhPFRiIlZ5M2ueYU/edit?usp=sharing

I hope it's okay to do so.

---

I could need some help with the following problem: I'm trying to create a summary sheet for a variety of data sheets. Each data sheet, i.e., "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", e.g., has an ID variable that I use for splitting my data within each data sheet.

What I'm trying to do is to loop through all my data sheets, grab the data in each sheet, split the data for each sheet by ID, so that I have all rows with As, Bs and Cs for each sheet, and then put all these pieces together BUT SEPARATED BY A COUPLE OF EMPTY ROWS in my summary sheet.

What I have done thus far is this:

```
function main() {
  
  // SETUP.
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var workbook = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
  
  
  // CREATE NEW SUMMARY SHEET.
  var targetSheet = workbook.getSheetByName("Summary");
  if (!targetSheet) {
    workbook.insertSheet("Summary",1);
  }
  
  
  // ARRAY OF SHEETS USED IN MY LOOP.
  var tabs = ["Sheet 1",
              "Sheet 2",
              "Sheet 3"];
  
  
  // LOOP FOR ALL SHEETS.
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var sheet = workbook.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
    
    
    // GRAB THE ORIGINAL DATA.
    var originalData = sheet.getRange(5, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-5, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    
    // SELECT ID AND SORT BY UNIQUE IDs.
    var range = sheet.getRange(5,2,sheet.getLastRow()-5,1).getValues();
    var range = [].concat.apply([], range);
    let uniqueValues = range.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
    
    
    // GRAB THE UNIQUE DATA PIECES IN EACH SHEET.
    for (var t = 0; t < uniqueValues.length; t++) {
      var filterText = uniqueValues[t];
      
      var newData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
        return item[1] === filterText;
      });

    // DO SOMETHING I HAVE YET TO DEFINE
    // e.g., exclude rows that fall beneath a certain threshold.
      
    // WRITE DATA PIECES BACK TO SUMMARY SHEET.
    workbook.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange(???).setValues(newData);

    }
  }
}
```

The code above works fine and does slice my data on different data sheets correctly. However, setting the pieces back together is an issue. Right now the data pieces of each iteration is overwritten by the next one.

What I need to do is to figure out a way how to grab these different slices of data based on my ID and then put them together in a way shown in my example data (linke above).

I think I'm lost somewhere between different loops and the data stored temporarily within the loops.

Comment: An image of your sheets might help us to visualize what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*After gathering the data you need to:*

- *Run through the rows*
- *Check the product name*
- *Push rows with the same product name to separate arrays*
- *Use `setValues()` to set the data of each product*
- *Add 4 blank rows*

#### Code Modifications:

Before your `LOOP THROUGH ALL SHEETS` for loop, add an array declaration:

```
var dataSets = [];
```

Then, replace the following line:

```
workbook.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange(???).setValues(newData);
```

With:

```
dataSets.push(newData);
```

And after the for loop, do the data processing set out in the first section of this answer:

```
// Create a 2D array to push the data to:
var allData = [[],[],[]];
  
// loop through the Data sets and push them to the correct element of allData:
dataSets.forEach(function(dataSet) {
  dataSet.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[1] == "Product A") {
      allData[0].push(row)
    }
    else if (row[1] == "Product B") {
      allData[1].push(row)
    }
    else if (row[1] == "Product C") {
      allData[2].push(row)
    }
  })
})

// Define the next row to add data to in the Summary sheet:
var nextRow = 1;

// Set the data to the Summary sheet:
allData.forEach(function(product) {
  var noOfColumns = product[0].length;
  var noOfRows = product.length;
  workbook.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange(nextRow, 1, noOfRows, noOfColumns).setValues(product)
  nextRow += noOfRows + 4;
});
```